# kill timer started with startTimer()

Tags: c++, qt

I have a timer, which I start in my start() function. It controls a timerEvent function, but I can't stop it. I tried killTimer() but I don't know its ID.

```
startTimer(60);
void Game::timerEvent(QTimerEvent *){}
killTimer(0);
```

The function just check for key-presses. killTimer(0) doesn't return an error, but every other id does, yet it still doesn't kill the timer. Is there a way to get the timer id via function?
The error: QObject::killTimer(): Error: timer id 1 is not valid for object 0x1c81bff8 (Game, ), timer has not been killed

EDIT: //small example

```
start(){ 
scene->setSceneRect(0,0,1200,800);
setScene(scene);

timerId = this->startTimer(60);
}

//when the game ends, i call konec();

konec(){
 if(winner==1 || winnerCPU==1){
     removeAllItems(); // this function attemps to stop the timer
     scene->setSceneRect(0,0,1200,800);
     setScene(scene);
     }

     //i have this on a timer also, it stats with start() but i stop the 
     //timer in removeAllItems()
     // may this cause multiple timers IDs?
     QRectF rect = scene->sceneRect();
     rect.translate(avto->speed, 0);
     scene->setSceneRect(rect);

removeAllItems(){ /

timer->stop();
timer2->stop();
mtimer->stop();
shifter->stop();
time->stop();
move_timer->stop();
this->killTimer(timerId);



QList<QGraphicsItem *> stvari = scene->items();
for(int i=0, n=stvari.size();i<n;i++){
    if((typeid(*(stvari[i]))==typeid(Button)) || (typeid(*
(stvari[i]))==typeid(QTableView)) ||
            (typeid(*(stvari[i]))==typeid(Count)) || (typeid(*
(stvari[i]))==typeid(Linija)) ||
            (typeid(*(stvari[i]))==typeid(Player)) || (typeid(*
(stvari[i]))==typeid(Player2)) ||
            (typeid(*(stvari[i]))==typeid(Sred)))
            scene->removeItem(stvari[i]);}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [definition](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#startTimer) of `startTimer` you see that it says:

> Starts a timer and returns a timer identifier, or returns zero if it could not start a timer.

So you need to use the `int` it returns in `killTimer`

Comment: but how do i get the value it returns?

Comment: `int timerId = myQtObj.startTimer();`

Comment: still says timerid is not valid for object

Comment: Are you passing the result to `killTimer` or still 0?

Comment: I'm passing it the timerId killTimer(timerId);

Comment: Show a reproducable example

Comment: in start(): timerId=this.startTimer(60); then when the game finishes i call destroyAllItems() and try to stop the timer with killTimer(timerId);

Comment: Im not very familliar with Qt but it might be due to the fact your destroying all objects before you stop your timer.

Comment: in the destroyAllItems function i first stop all my timers, then i delete the items.

Comment: Edit your question to a include a [proper example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i added it. if there doesn't seem to be a way to kill the timer, how could i change the timer to a QTimer? its supposed to call a function for keypresses timerEvent(QTimerEvent *) but it doesn't call it if u just connect it like a QTimer

Answer (score 0):

```
  int timerId;
  timerId = startTimer(60);
  killTimer(timerId);
```